# Virtualbox: scp between host and guest is very very slow

Tags: virtualbox, scp

I have install Virtualbox on a CentOS machine. The guests are CentOS machines too.
Their kernel is 2.6.18-194.3.1.el5 and they are CentOS 5.4.

The problem is that scp'ing files from a the guests to the host (or viceversa) is very slow (60.0KB/s).

scp'ing from a guest to a remote machine is instead very fast (11MB/s).

I searched on Google and there is a problem with a Linux kernel but it is not the one I am running.

I don't know what to do. I really need to copy files between machines at a reasonable rate.

I hope somebody can help.

Thanks,
Daniele

Answer (score 3):

Outside/in addition to ensuring you have the "Guest Additions" installed, you might also look into switching between the available virtual NIC types (AMD vs. Intel) for possible improvements.

Comment: That was it. I changed the Adapter Type from 'Internet PRO/1000 MT Desktop' to 'Intel PRO/1000 T Server'. Thanks!

Comment: A lot of times that all it takes. It's nice to have a few choices to help with getting things running.